# Как передать динамический массив в метод класса?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, динамические-массивы

Класс:

```
class Snumbers{
   double metod(double m[]) { 
   /*
   ---code---
   */ 
   return m[0]; // для примера
   }
};
```

Основная программа:

```
int main(){
   Snumbers A;
   int num; 

   cin >> num;
   double *m1 = new double[num];

   for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
      cin >> m1[i];
   }
   cout << A.metod(m1);
}
```

Вопрос такой, как мне передать массив в тот метод класса, чтобы потом я там с ним работал, и тот метод вернул то что я напишу?

**Обновление**

Забыл добавить `public` в классе перед методом. Вот как должно быть

```
 class Snumbers{
 public:
    double metod(double m[]) { 
    /*
       ---code---
    */ 
   return m[0]; // для примера
   }
 };
```

Получаю ошибку:

> [bcc32 Error] F1.cpp(27): E2247 'Snumbers::metod(double *)' is not accessible

Comment: А что не так с тем кодом, который вы привели?

Comment: Так это вы забыли `public`.

Comment: @SkiesX SO это не форум, когда вам наводящие вопросы в коментариях задют не нужно отвечать коментарием, нужно вопрос дополнять, поэтому текст ошибки вы должны в вопрос добавить. Понятно?

Comment: @Cerbo Извиняюсь:) Первый раз тут. Я вон в ответы добавил. Нормально будет?

Comment: @SkiesX Используйте, пожалуйста, возможность редактировать исходное сообщение, вместо публикации дополнений вопроса в виде ответов к нему.

Answer (score 3):

Тебе так же следует передавать размер массива в метод класса, иначе как ты с ним сможешь работать если не знаешь его размер?

```
double metod( double * arr, size_t size ) {
    ...
}

...

cout << A.metod( m1, num );
```

Comment: Я уже в методе узнаю размер массива.

Comment: Ты можешь знать размер если он - константа, или через какую-либо другую глобальную/классовую переменную. По-другому никак.